# Trying to get a mouseclick in canvas to add an Image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The teacher has asked us to create a Canvas with some quick interactive features (The Class is interactive 101. Go figure) So I decided to create a quick idea using my favourite sports team, the Montreal Canadians. I will separate the HTML from the JavaScript.

HTML(Named: MontrealSymbol.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Say Hello To...</h1>
    <h2>The MONTREAL CANADIENS!</h2>

    <canvas id="mCanvas" width="320" height="240">
        <p>Sorry, The Canvas element is not supported in this browser :(</p> 

    </canvas>

    <!-- Don't load/run Javascript until Canvas has loaded -->
    <script src="MontrealSymbol.js">
</script>      
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="mSymbol()">Draw the Symbol of the Greats!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="clearBoard()">Clear The Board</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript(Named: MontrealSymbol.js):

```
//test to see if we're connected.

console.log("Javascript Initialized");

//1. set up the canvas as an object with 2D context
var canvas = document.getElementById("mCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

//2. setting up font for later use
context.font = '24pt Verdana';

//Red Background
context.fillStyle = "#eb1919";
context.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 240);

//---------------X, Y---W, H

//White bar
context.fillStyle = "white";
context.fillRect(0, 75, 320, 85);

//Blue Bar
context.fillStyle = "blue";
context.fillRect(0, 80, 320, 75);

//border
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 5);

context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 240);

context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(0, 235, 320, 5);

context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(317, 0, 3, 240);

function mSymbol(){
console.log("Drawing Montreal Canadiens Symbol");
base_image = new Image();
base_image.src = 'images/mCanadiens3.jpg';
base_image.onload = function(){
context.drawImage(base_image, 75, 62);}
}

function clearBoard(){
console.log("Clearing the Board");
context.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
drawBack();
}

function drawBack(){
//Background
context.fillStyle = "#eb1919";
context.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 240);
//---------------X, Y---W, H

//layer one
context.fillStyle = "white";
context.fillRect(0, 75, 320, 85);

//layer two
context.fillStyle = "blue";
context.fillRect(0, 80, 320, 75);

//border
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 5);

context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 240);

context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(0, 235, 320, 5);

context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(317, 0, 3, 240);
}

context.beginPath();
context.arc(20, 20, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = '111';
context.stroke();
```

This runs fine. And I apologize that I don't have the code I've been attempting to use to do the mouse event. I've used a couple different people's ideas, but nothing seems to work. I just keep getting errors. I probably forgot something. But If someone could come up with a quick solution, What I want is a Mouse Click event that draws the last 7 lines of the JavaScript on click, and won't repeat when holding the mouse down.

Comment: Please post some sample code of one of your attempts anyhow (and not too much boiler plate code that isn't relevant to the problem). Also, what should the user click on? And are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: We are using simple Javascript for this assignment. It's just to get us into the usage of Canvas and making it Interactive. As for what they should click on, the assignment is to just have them able to click the canvas and have a pre-drawn item show up after clicking. In this case, it's just a quickly drawn hockey puck. As for the Mouse Click event, that is where I am having issues. W3Schools says one thing, this site says another. I can't find a simple way of just drawing the item. If I wasn't working midnights all weekend, and it wasn't due Monday, I would ask one of my Classmates for help

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<canvas id="mCanvas" width="320" height="240" onclick="canvasClick()">
    <p>Sorry, The Canvas element is not supported in this browser :(</p> 
</canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function canvasClick(){
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(20, 20, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = '111';
    context.stroke();
}
```